# Harvard referencing

Tags: harvard-style

I am using natbib and agsm for harvard style referencing.

My related code is

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}


\bibliography{bibliography/bibliography}
```

Even I could get the reference list....how to do that? I am using the Imperial College template. But I used this `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` except this `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`. Then only I got this file. I want to get haravard references.

ex: in `bibliography.bib` file

```
@article{Roberts95b, 
 author = {A. J. Roberts and A. Cronin}, 
 journal = {Physica A}, 
 pages = {867--878}, 
 title = {Unbiased estimation of multi-fractal 
 dimensions of finite data sets}, 
 volume = 233, 
 year = 1996, 
}
```

output:

> A. J. Roberts and A. Cronin. Unbiased estimation of multi-fractal dimensions of finite data sets. *Physica A*, 233:867-878, 1996

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the problem you're looking to solve. Part of the issue may be that the term "harvard" is both a synonym for a certain style of *citing* pieces -- the "author-year citation style" -- as well as a specific LaTeX package that consists of a main style file called, you guessed it, `harvard.sty`, and more than a half dozen specific bibliography style files; one of these is `agsm.bst`. The `.bst` file determines the formatting of the entries in the references section. If it's part of an entire package (as is the case for `agsm.bst`), it may make use of specialized macros defined by the package (here: `harvard.sty`).

To use `agsm` with `natbib` rather than `harvard`, it is necessary to load a little utility package called `har2nat`. (I think the name suggests what it does.) The following setup should work for you:

```
\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

Incidentally, the `plainnat` bibliography style is compatible with both numeric and author-year style citations. To generate author-year style citations, load the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear`:

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

With either setup, you'll get author-year style citations. The references, of course, will be formatted differently than if you used `agsm`. Choose whichever style that fits your needs and requirements.